# How to iterate each cell of data column,convert and append each cell?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary

Each row of a data frame column is a list of dictionaries.

I want to convert the list of dictionaries to a new data frame with each dictionary as a new cell in my data frame. The keys of the dictionaries as the columns. Each dictionary has 44 keys, so I have 44 columns.
I need to do this for all the rows (lists) of the data frame column and append each newly transformed data frame cell to the existing data frame.

My problem is, not all the dictionaries from my list are transformed to a cell in a new data frame. Many of the dictionaries are missed.

```
My data frame column df[‘data’] looks like this:

 0 [
  { "name": "Tom", "age": 10 },
  { "name": "Mark", "age": 5 },
  { "name": "Pam", "age": 7 },
  { "name": "Dick", "age": 12 }
 ]

1 [
  { "name": “Ash", "age": 20 },
  { "name": “Jim", "age": 54 },
  { "name": “Sam", "age": 29 },
  { "name": “Poo", "age": 15 }
  ]
len(df) = 2
```

Output should be like this: df_all

```
Name Age
Tom  10
Mark  5
Pam   7
Dick  12
Ash   20
Jim   54
Sam   29
Poo   15

len(df_all) =8
```

**My code is below:**

```
#Reading all the rows of the column ‘data’ from the df
data = df['data'].iloc[:1500]
len(data) #1500

#Creating an empty data frame
df_append = pd.DataFrame([])

#Iterating over all rows(lists of dictionaries) of a data frame and converting 
#each list to a data frame and keep appending to it.

for each_item in data:
    df_each_row = pd.DataFrame(each_item)
    df_all = df_append.append(df_each_row)
df_all

len(df_all) #501
```

If each row(list) in 'data' has 10 dictionaries, then there should be 1500*10(15000) rows present in the final dataframe. Instead I get only 501 rows. However, I get 44 columns correctly.

Comment: Sorry, can you post a few rows of your data here in the question? It isn't exactly easy to visualise your problem or formulate a solution without that much.

Comment: Is it possible that there are only 501 index values in `df['data']`, up to index `1500`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have updated with my sample input and how I want my output to be. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, reversed the vote.

Comment: @andrew_reece Yes, that might be the case. So what can be the solution for this? Any suggestions please? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, are you loading this from JSON? There are possibly better ways to load your data such that you don't have to reshape it later.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Well, I am not sure. I guess, data was got from facebook api which was directly loaded into the MongoDB. However I got the data in this format where this was one of the columns.

Comment: @AshishPowani Okay. See my answer using `np.concatenate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.concatenate` + `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

```
df

                                                 col
0  [{'age': 10, 'name': 'Tom'}, {'age': 5, 'name'...
1  [{'age': 20, 'name': 'Ash'}, {'age': 54, 'name'...

pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.col).tolist())

   age  name
0   10   Tom
1    5  Mark
2    7   Pam
3   12  Dick
4   20   Ash
5   54   Jim
6   29   Sam
7   15   Poo
```

If what you have is a series (not a dataframe), you can just to `np.concat(s)` where `s` is your `pd.Series`.

Comment: My reputation is less than 15. So, although my upvote is recorded, it does not change the publicly displayed score.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
from  itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(df['col'].values.tolist())))
print (df)

   age  name
0   10   Tom
1    5  Mark
2    7   Pam
3   12  Dick
4   20   Ash
5   54   Jim
6   29   Sam
7   15   Poo
```

Another solution, improved [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47216661/2901002):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.col.values).tolist())
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [29]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df['col']).tolist()))
1 loop, best of 3: 330 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(df['col'].values.tolist()))))
10 loops, best of 3: 81.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: This solution worked. Thank you. It took 133.18 sec while the solution given by @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ took 117.90 sec.

Comment: Interesting, what about `pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.col.values).tolist())` ? I think it should be faster.

Comment: I test it in python 3 under windows 7, pandas version is 0.20.3